# Why does Bitmap cause rule CA2000, but Image does not?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dispose, code-analysis

There are a lot of questions on SO lamenting the fact that Code Analysis rule CA2000 is being applied possibly too rigorously by VS2010, but I seem to have run into a case where it should be applied, but isn't.

Consider the following code:

```
Image srcImage = Image.FromFile(source);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);

using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(newImage))
{
    gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));
}
newImage.Save(destination, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Now if I run Code Analysis in Visual Studio 2010 on this, it will complain about **newImage** not being disposed (easy fix, put it in another using block), but it doesn't complain about **srcImage** (which also has a Dispose() method that I'm never calling). Does anyone know why Code Analysis doesn't complain here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it should "complain about srcImage" too, however I *guess* that it doesn't complain about it because you are passing it to the `DrawImage` method "`gr.DrawImage(srcImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight));`", So either it is not smart enough to know that it will not being used for more actions after the method returned, or maybe it assumed that you used it in `gr` instance that will be disposed. Anyway you should use `using` for `srcImage` just like what you are doing with `newImage` and don't follow the Code Analysis on that.

Comment: I thought that at first, but then I looked at other CA2000 questions on SO and pretty much all of them have the rule triggered by just such passing of argument to another function (though usually with constructors involved). It's odd that a rule this annoying (to a lot of people, judging by the number of SO questions) would be so forgiving in this situation.

Comment: Yup, I agree that it is annoying, however we should "like you already did" not relying on Code Analysis to fix our code problems, instead just using them to double check and see if we forget about something here and there...

Comment: Yeah... but that kind of defeats the purpose of such tools. The reason I use them is so they can point out locations where I did something wrong, to save me the trouble to go through the entire giant code-base hunting for little things like this.

Answer (score 5):

CA2000 and the similar/related CA2213 (DisposableFieldsShouldBeDisposed) and CA1001 (TypesThatOwnDisposableFieldsShouldBeDisposable) rules are rather strict about how they recognize "ownership" of a disposable.  They will only consider your code to be the owner of a disposable instance if an instance constructor is used to create the instance directly in your code.  Since you use Image.FromFile to create the instance for srcImage, the rule doesn't recognize your code as the owner.

If you disagree with this rule behaviour, you may want to create a bug report at https://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/feedback.  (If you care about the disposable field rules, you might want to vote for the existing https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/485291/typesthatowndisposablefieldsshouldbedisposable-rule-ca1001-is-too-permissive suggestion while you're at it.)

Comment: Is there any way such a rule change could me made really useful without going back and tagging a lot of methods with attributes indicating that they should be regarded as taking over, relinquishing, or fudging ownership of an IDisposable (i.e. varying behavior depending upon factors a the tool shouldn't be expected to track)?  Introducing such behavior may be worthwhile, but adding enough tags to get clean reports could be a lot of work.

Comment: @supercat: It's quite feasible for the rule to be authored in such a way as to detect that an invoked method is a factory method that creates a new instance of a disposable without storing that instance in its own state.  That said, the rule would not be able to handle complex creation patterns like IoC use without adding some metadata.  However, any attributes should go on the factory methods, not their consumers.

Comment: If the scanner could see the code for the factories, it could probably determine that they create and return new IDisposable instances.  Not all factories have code that would be accessible to the scanner, though.  Adding recognition of factories would make the scanner generate more useful warnings, but also more spurious ones, unless it could also recognize when IDisposable objects are legitimately handed off; such recognition would raise a number of tricky issues, though....

Comment: Among other things, how aggressive should the scanner be in requiring that code which creates an IDisposable for the purpose of handing it off go to great lengths to ensure it's disposal in the face of exceptions? Saying "thing = new DisposableType1(new DisposableType2());" creates the possibility of leaking a DisposableType2() if the outer constructor throws an exception, but the code to handle that scenario is really icky and poses its own issues. What would have been best would have been if a constructor that threw an exception could expose the partially-constructed object.

Comment: The Dispose handler for such an object would have to be prepared for the possibility that the object wasn't fully constructed, but constructors could be far more robust.  BTW, I'd also like to see a 'using out' construct which would specify that the object being guarded should have Dispose called if an exception is thrown, but not if the 'using out' block runs to completion.